# Can I add metadata to a namedtuple?

Tags: python

I have a namedtuple like so:

```
tup = namedtuple(
    'MyData', [
        'field_1',
        'field_2
    ])
```

what I want to be able to do is attach metadata to each value, for instance, to know whether the fields are alphanumeric:

```
tup = namedtuple(
    'MyData', [
        {name:'field1', metadata: {is_alpha: True}},
        {name:'field2', metadata: {is_alpha: False}},
    ])
```

I can't find anything in the documentation defining any sort of interface like this, but im wondering if any of you know if its possible. Thanks!

Comment: If it isn't in the docs ...

Comment: Is the question limited to python2?

Answer (score 0):

A namedtuple doesn't support this exactly as you have it above but it's a class so you can simply add additional properties by doing something like `tup.field1_is_alpha = True` after you have `tup` defined (as at the top of the post).

Another potential solution is to set each field of `tup` to another tuple (or namedtuple or class) such as..

`t1 = tup( (1,True), (5,False) )`

The downside here is that the metadata goes with each instance of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: In addition, you can use the class `namedtype()` returns as the base class of your own customized version.